# Organize media uploads in folders - I have a physical access to (my) server

Tags: media-library, uploads

I'm very new to Wordpress. With the help of my friend I installed Wordpress on my server and finally we have our web online. However, I would like to upload some content in media library but I need to organize it in folders. Now we organized it with date-time hierarchy but its not enough. Is it possible having an access to the physical server where I have my site to create some directories and upload files to it using wordpress (I would like to create them inside the date-time directories)?

Where do I need to create such folders, how can I check where my friend installed wordpress and find the directory I can create some subdirectories?

Do I need a wordpress plugin or can it be done manually on server?

We installed our wordpress on Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Comment: What kind of directory structure are you after?

Comment: You can use a plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/physical-custom-upload-folder/ if you want to create custom physical folders when uploading new files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you needed help to install WordPress I recommend you do not use custom media folder.

Either stick to the Year/Month structure default, or put all your media in the wp-content/uploads folder (in Settings > Media > uncheck Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders).

[image: Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders]

Most WP installations use less than 100 photos and other media. That is not too much to handle in one folder or in Year/Month structure.

Do not use the media library as a reservoir of unused photos you may "someday" use. That makes it unmanageable.

Instead upload the image(s) you want to use in each post/page as you need it. If you want to reuse images down the track you can find them via your pages or the media library.

Pro Tip: Use the Title, Alt text and Description fields in the media library to describe the picture so you can search for it by text. e.g. Photo of Jerry fishing on the lake.

Pro Top 2: Use the caption field to put your "photo credit" info and description e.g. PaulZag at work. Photo by Erica Massingham/Some Stock Library

If you absolutely insist on custom folders use https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library

It allows you to fully manage your media files with the ability to add taxonomies (categories and tags).

I would avoid renaming or creating new directories manually within the uploads directory on your server. It's important that new upload directories are registered through the WP database.

Comment: +1 I think that plugin recommendations, like your answer, should be made in comments, not in answers, but I really like the plugin that you have recommended. The idea to use taxonomies to organize attachemnts is really a much better idea than organize attachments using physical folders in a dynamic web.

Comment: I agree. Now that I've been here a while, I'm not a fan of answers that involve plugins. Glad the solution worked :)